# unable to setup persistent undo history in Vim

Tags: vimrc

I've looked up and tried several of the following post up here regarding setting up persistent undo history in vim, but still I'm not able to do so. (macOSX Mojave)

here are some info:

:version

```
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
```

vimrc file = ~/.vim/.vimrc

```
":highlight Normal ctermfg=grey ctermbg=darkblue                                          
:let $MYVIMRC="~/.vim/.vimrc"

set undofile                                                                              
set undodir=/Users/dave/.vim/undodir

let mapleader = "\<Space>"

:nnoremap <leader>sv :source $MYVIMRC<cr>                                                 
:nnoremap <leader>ev :vsplit $MYVIMRC<cr>
```

~/.bash_profile

```
alias vim="vim -S ~/.vim/.vimrc"
```

Inside of /undodir:

%Users%dave%.vim%.vimrc %Users%dave%test.js

However when I load "test.js" and press u, vim responds with "already oldest change".

Comment: No answer to you actual question, but unless you have a really good reason for it, I’d recommend allowing Vim to find your .vimrc in the usual way rather than your slightly convoluted method. Specifically, remove your bash alias, remove the line overwriting the $MYVIMRC variable, and rename your file from `~/.vim/.vimrc` to `~/.vim/vimrc`.

Comment: Are you sure youve edited test.js such that it has an undo history?

Comment: @Rich, I forgot the reason why I did it that way, but your suggestion help fixed my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your alias:

```
alias vim="vim -S ~/.vim/.vimrc"
```

Note that sourcing a script with `-S` is **not** the same as using that file as your vimrc.

From [`:help -S`](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#-S) (emphasis mine):

> The `{file}` will be sourced **after** the first file has been read.

So, in effect, you're only setting `'undofile'` and `'undodir'` after you've already opened your `test.js`. If you simply opened `vim` with no files and then opened the file with `:e test.js`, restoring undo might have worked.

If you want to load your vimrc from a non-standard location, then [`-u`](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#-u) is what you want instead... But there's really no reason to do that, just store your vimrc at one of the standard locations and get rid of that alias instead.